# Extraction particular portion from text file using python

Tags: python, validation, information-extraction

As mention below I have A1 to A300 Specific set of information in a single text file named full change.txt

If *****
Begin
****A1
End
Go

If *****
Begin
****A2
End
Go
………..

I have 300 files and each file saved as A1.txt, A2.txt till A300txt

My request is I want to split each set based on A1,A2 separately from full change.txt and append them at end of the line of those 300 files based on file name

Example :
Extract the below snippet

If *****
Begin
****A1
End
Go

From full change.txt to A1.txt

Please let me know the solution

It would be really helpful

I tried split function but unable to achieve

Comment: Read each line and append that line to the appropriate text file. What's going wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.